# How to create a stack of an uploaded image in a shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below which makes image recognition. I upload the image below and it is displayed as you will see. The issue is that I want to use the name of this file ("DJI_0104.jpg") inside the `stack()` function in order to create a stack of the image. Then I plot the result (textures). Basically I am looking for a way to use only the name of the uploaded image -like in R104() which works-. You can find the .jpg [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zq0luq5f7bpvdoo/DJI_0104.JPG?dl=0)

```
library(shiny)
library(base64enc)
library(raster)
library(glcm)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 30*1024^2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("upload", "Upload image", accept = "image/png"),
  uiOutput("image"),
  plotOutput("textures")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  base64 <- reactive({
    inFile <- input[["upload"]]
    if(!is.null(inFile)){
      dataURI(file = inFile$datapath, mime = "image/png")
    }
  })

  output[["image"]] <- renderUI({
    if(!is.null(base64())){
      tags$div(
        tags$img(src= base64(), width="100%"),
        style = "width: 400px;"
      )
    }
  })
  #That does not work
  R105 <- reactive({
    stack(base64())
  })
  #That works
  R104 <- reactive({
    stack("DJI_0104.jpg")
  })
  textures <- reactive({
    glcm(raster(R105(), layer=3))
  })
  output$textures<-renderPlot({
    #Create a stack of the image

    plot(textures())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I don't understand but if you want the file name, it is in `inFile$name` I think.

Comment: so I should use stack(inFile$name)?

Comment: `R105 <- reactive({req(input[["upload"]]); input[["upload"]][["name"]]})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find more details [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/fileInput.html), but here is a solution: in the `base64()` reactive, `inFile` is built after the output of `fileInput()`, output which possesses 4 fields: `name`, `size`, `type` and `datapath` (see link above). 
As [Stéphane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/st%c3%a9phane-laurent) underlined, using `inFile$name` shall make your shinyApp work.

Best.